# add the key name and value for the same array in php

Tags: php

I have some array like this how can i split the key and value in php ?

```
[A0E4NL014XVM273] => Array
    (
        [0] => qexixdb
    )

[A0E4UK024XVM014_Clone] => Array
    (
        [0] => pe8w3100
        [1] => pe8w3100
    )
```

**Tried Query**

```
foreach($vm_array  as $vmkey=> $vmvalue){
    $varray[] = $vmvalue;
    /*foreach($vmvalue as $vmvalue=> $vmvalufmarray){
        $vm_array[$vmkey][] = $vmvalufmarray.',';
    }*/
}
```

**Expected Output**

```
[A0E4UK024XVM014_Clone] => pe8w3100,pe8w3100
```

Comment: Just implode the sub array with `,`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to make a function called `implode()`.

```
foreach($vm_array  as $vmkey=> $vmvalue){
    $varray[$vmkey] = implode(",", $vmvalue);
}
print_r($varray);
```

Answer (score 2):

Try using PHP's [implode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php) on the inner array;

```
foreach($vm_array as $vmkey => $vmvalue){

    $vm_array[$vmkey] = implode(",", $vmvalue);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried your example and simulated my own, if my understanding is right, if you want to retain them in the array.

```
$test = array("[A0E4NL014XVM273]" => array("qexixdb"),"[A0E4UK024XVM014_Clone]" => array("pe8w3100","pe8w3100"));


echo "<pre>";
    var_dump($test);
echo "</pre>";

$new_arr_ = array();
foreach($test as $id => $value) {

    $new_val = "";
    for($i = 0, $ctr_val = count($value); $i < $ctr_val; $i++) {
        $old_id = "";
        if($id != $old_id) {
            if($i < ($ctr_val - 1)) {
                $new_val .= $value[$i] . ",";
            } else {
                $new_val .= $value[$i];
            }
            $old_id = $id;
        }
    }
    $new_arr_[] = array($id => $new_val);
}

echo "<pre>";
    var_dump($new_arr_);
echo "</pre>";
```

Or if just one array:

```
$new_arr_ = array();
foreach($test  as $key=> $value){
    $new_arr_[key] = implode(",", $value);
}

echo "<pre>";
    var_dump($new_arr_);
echo "</pre>";
```

Hope it helps.